# Retrieving connection string in integration test

Tags: integration-testing, mstest, cqrs, c#-7.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to do some integration tests for my asp.net Core 2.1 project.

I initialise on startup file my connection string but when i run the test it still empty in handler, what is wrong on my code?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Method1()
    {
        var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
                            .UseEnvironment("Development") 
                            .UseStartup<Startup>(); 
        HttpRequestMessage getRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "api/action")
        {                
        };
        getRequest.Headers.Add("userId", "4622");
        getRequest.Headers.Add("clientId", "889");

        using (var server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder))
        using (var client = server.CreateClient())
        {
            var result = await client.SendAsync(getRequest);  
            ...             
        }
   }
```

**Startup**

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
        Configuration = configuration;

}
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.Configure<SqlConfig>(options =>
    {
       options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    });
    ...
}
```

**SqlConfig**

```
public class SqlConfig
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public abstract class SqlServerQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> : BaseQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
     where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
   public SqlServerQueryHandler(IOptions<SqlConfig> connectionString)
    {
        this.ConnectionString = connectionString.Value.ConnectionString;
    }

   protected string ConnectionString { get; }
}
```

Comment: How is configuration created?

Comment: @Nkosi if i understand your question, the configuration is created when the startup file is executed and this file is executed when i create an instance of WebHostBuilder

Comment: There are different ways that configuration is created but you have not shown how it is in you startup class. That is why I had to ask. Is it injected or are you initializing it manually?

Comment: I am referring to `IConfiguration Configuration`

Comment: @Nkosi I updated my post, you can have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178022/discussion-between-omar-amezoug-and-nkosi).

Comment: add a local appsettings.json file with the connection string and see if it finds it

Comment: Also make sure you added `services.AddOptions();` in start up as well

Comment: @Nkosi i did both but still empty!

Answer (score 1):

what solve my probleme is the following code :

```
public class TestStartup : Startup
{
    public TestStartup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env) : base(configuration)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        this.Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

Include the appsettings.json via interface on the output directory

[image]